# create a universal function for selecting in php from db (SQLI)

Tags: php, mysqli

i have this code but unable to execute it
it says `Call to undefined method Dbh::query()` 
what can be done to fix this am a noob in php and have just started can some one please help 
also i am using `mysqli`

```
public function setSingleSelect($whatColumn,$tableName, $whereColumn,$queryCondition,$setColumn)
{
     $this->whatColumn = $whatColumn;
     $this->tableName = $tableName;
     $this->whereColumn = $whereColumn;
     $this->queryCondition = $queryCondition;
     $this->setColumn = $setColumn;
}
 public function singleSelect (){

   $sql ="SELECT {$this->whatColumn} FROM {$this->tableName}";
   $result = $conn->query($sql);

    return $result;
 }
```

Comment: what is this `GLOBAL $conn;`  I mean I assume it's some kind of DB class but without it, it's just guessing.

Comment: ohh that lol just ignore that will 
I have removed it

Comment: Without `global` you have an undefined variable `$conn`.

Comment: Why not `retun $this->conn->query` and make `$conn` a property of the class

Comment: Anyway, the problem is pretty clear. Whatever the value of `$conn` is, it doesn't have a `query()` method.

Comment: could you provide a solution please

Comment: Only if you provide the complete code and not a snippet that by itself makes very little sense

Comment: To ask an On Topic questions, please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
 and [What topics to avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)
 and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: @q1693033, you already have a solution: properly define your `$conn` variable. Whatever that object is, it doesn't have a `query` method. Asking, "please provide a solution," is essentially asking the community to define a database connection for you.